# regex seems to work but does not

Tags: php, regex

I'm tring to get a function to parse the data from the source of a website:

```
function parse ($source) {
$res = array();
$matches = array();
$rx = "#^\s*routes\.push\(\{'start':([a-zA-Z0-9':,\-\s]*),\s'finish':([a-zA-Z0-9':,\-\s]*),\s'[a-zA-Z0-9':,\-\s]*':([0-9\s\-]){1,4},[a-zA-Z0-9':,\.\-\s]*}\);\s*$#";
preg_match_all($rx, $source, $matches);
    for($i=0,$_i=count($matches[1]);$i<$_i;++$i) {
    $res[$i][0]=$matches[1][$i];
    $res[$i][1]=$matches[2][$i];
    }
```

The code to be parsed is like :

```
routes.push({'start': tokyo, 'finish': LA, 'blue': 18, 'arcoffset': -20, 'transpacific': true});
    routes.push({'start': tokyo, 'finish': seattle, 'blue': 6, 'arcoffset': 5, 'transpacific': true});
    routes.push({'start': tokyo, 'finish': sanjose, 'blue': 12, 'arcoffset': -4, 'transpacific': true});
    routes.push({'start': amsterdam, 'finish': tokyo, 'blue': 5, 'green': 2, 'arcoffset': 20});
```

The problem is that nothing goes in the arrays.
And when I check the regexp by doing
    echo preg_match_all($rx, $page, $matches);

it returns 0
So there might be a problem with my regexp, but according to Regex Tester, it's OK:

[Check regex: http://regexpal.com?...](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5Cs%2aroutes%5C.push%5C%28%5C%7B%27start%27%3a%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%27%3a%5C-%5Cs%5D%2a%29,%5Cs%27finish%27%3a%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%27%3a%5C-%5Cs%5D%2a%29,%5Cs%2a%27%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%27%3a%5C-%5Cs%5D%2a%27%3a%28%5B0-9%5Cs%5C-%5D%29%7B1,4%7D,%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%27%3a,%5C.%5C-%5Cs%5D%2a%7D%5C%29;%5Cs%2a%24&input=%09routes.push%28%7B%27start%27%3a%20tokyo,%20%27finish%27%3a%20LA,%20%27blue%27%3a%2018,%20%27arcoffset%27%3a%20-20,%20%27transpacific%27%3a%20true%7D%29;%0A%09routes.push%28%7B%27start%27%3a%20tokyo,%20%27finish%27%3a%20seattle,%20%27blue%27%3a%206,%20%27arcoffset%27%3a%205,%20%27transpacific%27%3a%20true%7D%29;%0A!)

Comment: I would pass the data to a server side js engine -> node.js. Also you might have a look at the [v8 js engine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) which can be used as an extension to PHP

Comment: I am not familiar with node.js I don't think i would really need it. Only this parsing is required for me.

Comment: Is the first `([a-zA-Z0-9':\-\s]*)` going to stop at ' tokyo, ', or is it also going to eat the rest of the line through `true`? You might need to specify a "non-greedy match".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the ^ end $ and say: the whole string ahs to match this pattern.. so not even repeated.. try to remove them so make your pattern like this:

```
$rx = "/\s*routes\.push\(\{'start':([a-zA-Z0-9':,\-\s]*),\s'finish':([a-zA-Z0-9':,\-\s]*),\s'[a-zA-Z0-9':,\-\s]*':([0-9\s\-]){1,4},[a-zA-Z0-9':,\.\-\s]*}\);\s*/";
```

Comment: you rule. I was trying to dispose of the # instead of the ^  $

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want matching 3 things : 2 cities and 1 number.

```
$rx = "\{'start':([a-zA-Z]*),\s'finish':([a-zA-Z]*),\s'[a-zA-Z]*':\s([0-9\s\-]{1,4})";
```

Comment: True but who says he doesn't want to include routes.push.. Maybe he want to write some other function which makes persons.push for example.